# tfs build server to set assembly specific version

Tags: tfs, msbuild, version, .net-assembly, build-server

Using a build server, is it possible to set to true the attribute 'Specific Version' of all the assemblies refereneced by project(s) being built?

If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe you can do it automatically(except hacking at the xml in the csproj files), the only way is to manually set each reference in each project.

Comment: thanks for the (late) reply  :) Indeed I could never find a way to do it automatically, so I wrote a custom batch in order to force specfic version = true in every csproj. Thanks !